# Django self-referencing nested QuerySets

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

How can I represent this simple SQL using Django ORM?

```
SELECT * FROM alerts a1 WHERE timestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM alerts a2
        WHERE a1.category = a2.category
        AND   a1.type     = a2.type
)
```

The alerts table in this case is a history of all the possible alerts that happened, with a category tag on each - and the query returns the latest alerts for each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to translate your query directly to django-orm. You will need to use raw query, or search for a different solution.

Here is one possible proposition:

- I assume that `pk` is just like timestamp, the later created - the higher. So I group cols by `category` and `type` and then select MAX('pk') instead of MAX('timestamp').

  ```
  latest_events_pks = Event.objects.values('category', 'typ') \
                                   .annotate(max=Max('pk')) \
                                   .values_list('max', flat=True)
  ```

  It generates a query like this:

  ```
  SELECT MAX("event"."id") AS "max" FROM "event" 
  GROUP BY "event"."category", "event"."typ"
  ```
- [values_list()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) returned a list of id for example: `[1, 15, 20, 22]`. So it is possible to select appropriate events:

  ```
  Event.objects.filter(id__in=latest_events_pks)
  ```

It is 2 queries but they should be more efficient than a query with sub query.

Comment: Good idea about using the pk.

Comment: It actually does only one single query with a nested select. With the internal select being an aggregate on grouped categories and types, which does exactly what I asked in the OP to do.

   SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE id IN (                                               
       SELECT MAX(U0.id) AS maxid FROM alerts U0                                    
           GROUP BY U0."category", U0."subtype"                                     
   )